# Trapping rain water ii (LeetCode) with hole (0)

Tags: algorithm, graphics, graph-algorithm

> https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water-ii/
>
> Given an m x n matrix of positive integers representing the height of
>   each unit cell in a 2D elevation map, compute the volume of water it
>   is able to trap after raining.

A slight addition is if there's a hole in it and whole platform is in air? How much can it actually store?

While i can look for bounding region around the hole and calculate how much water is wasted there, i can only define a rectangular bounding region (Case 1), but for the second case how can you locate and calculate water in this region:

[image: []]

If i just look for rectangular region which consists the bounding region defined by grey lines, calculate water stored in here then subtract from total, water stored in green region will be removed which shouldn't be. And the bigger problem what if it doesn't exist at all?

[image: []]

Or is there any approach i'm missing, any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why restrict yourself to rectangular regions? I would start growing regions around local minima until the region boundary exceeds the matrix boundary. Slightly related: [Maximally stable extremal regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions).

Comment: Well, i am using same function to calculate the water which "should" be lost because of the hole. And this can only accept region as a rectangle.(Second image). Also how would you store an arbitrary region? Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here’ the approach that worked for me.

I was looking at separate cells, not regions.

Let `a[i][j]` be the total height of combined stone (or whatever material is it) and water above it.

Then we have:

```
a[i][j] = max(height[i][j], min(a[i+1][j], a[i][j+1], a[i-1][j], a[i][j-1]))
```

The “max” part is to prevent the value from being less than the stone part. And the “min” part is to make sure that water is held by the adjacent cells.

For boundaries the water level is zero so `a[i][j] = height[i][j]`. For other cells we can start with a very big number.

To illustrate this a little bit: suppose you know for sure that the water level for an adjacent cell can't be more than 7 (for example). Then the water level for your current cell also can't be more than 7: there's literally nothing to hold the water from flowing in direction of that adjacent cell.

By the way, if you have a "hole" in a cell then a[i][j] = 0 since no water can be accumulated there.

We can repeatedly apply that formula as kind of “relaxation” until it’s no longer possible. When it’s no longer possible we have our final configuration and we just need to calculate the water volume.

For procedure to be efficient we can go from top to bottom applying:

```
a[i][j] = max(height[i][j], min(a[i-1][j], a[i][j-1]))
```

and then from bottom to top applying:

```
a[i][j] = max(height[i][j], min(a[i+1][j], a[i][j+1]))
```

repeating it again an again while at least one cell value changes.

Comment: @HimanshuSurana well, at least it works good enough to pass the leetcode tests :)

Comment: I can't understand the reasoning behind doing so, could you please elaborate  a little. Thanks for helping.